# Целесообразно ли написание моделей для Entity Framework вручную при подходе Database First?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Я пишу программу на WPF с подключением базы данных через **Entity Framework** используя подход **Database First**.

Есть ли смысл писать модели и классы вручную или лучше использовать автоматическую генерацию?

Comment: Как проще, так и поступайте.

Comment: в общем случае Code First всегда удобнее, а там смотрите сами

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать автоматическую генерацию - так вероятность сделать ошибку меньше. Но могут получится не совсем красивые классы. Поэтому всегда лучше использовать метод Code First - у разработчика больше контроля.

Comment: Никогда не говорите всегда

Comment: Как хочу, так и буду говорить, у Вас ещё забыл спросить. Если есть возможность использовать Code Firts - надо использовать Code First.